# Preventing the browser's autosuggest when using an autocompleter with jQuery

Tags: jquery, browser, autocomplete, behavior, autosuggest

I'm using a small autocompleter function with jQuery.

That works well.

The problem is that when I'm typing a text in the input, my browser suggests me some of the previous texts I've typed before.

That part covers up the first answer of my autocompleter lookup function...

Here is a snapshot of the problem (the box where "lemp" appears) :

[bug_autosuggest.jpg](http://famille.lhuillier.free.fr/images/bug_autosuggest.jpg)

Is there a way to disable this behaviour ?

I mean "without going in the client-side settings of the browser".

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the `autocomplete` attribute to `"off"` on your `input` elements, or on your `form` element itself.

```
<form action="?" method="post" autocomplete = "off">
   ...
</form>
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/how_to_turn_off_form_autocompletion#How_to_Turn_Off_the_Autocompletion_Feature).

You may want to add it with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that's exactly what I wanted. It works fine now, with all browsers I've tested. Thanks a lot !